# Filter JFace ComboViewer by entering text

Tags: java, filter, combobox, swt, jface

Im using a `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboViewer` to show Names of some objects. If i have like hundreds of those objects it gets very difficult to find the right object very quickly.
By default the ComboViewer filters only for the first entered "Letter" but that is not the best solution for me, cause i might have Objects with names like:

```
"MyObject 1"
"MyObejct 2"
"MyObject 3"
```

and so on.

Currently im having this:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
myObjects.add(MyObject("One"));
myObjects.add(MyObject("Two"));
myObjects.add(MyObject("ThreeOne"));
myObjects.add(MyObject("ThreeTwo"));
ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(parent, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
comboViewer.setLabelProider(new LabelProvider(){
@Override
public String getText(final Object element){
  if(element instanceof MyObject){
    return MyObject.getName();
  }
  return super.getText(element);
}
comboViewer.setInput(myObjects);
```

Now i want to achieve the following.
When the User hits "O" then the MyObject "One" should be selected in the dropdownlist. When he hits "Th" then the MyObject "ThreeOne" should be selected in the dropdownlist.
When entering "ThreeT" then the MyObejct "ThreeTwo" should be selected and so on.
I hope it is clear what i mean with this.

I already tried `org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.AutoCompleteField` but that does not always filter the correct Items. Cause there can be empty spaces in the MyObject's Name.
A simple Textfield with Autocompletion oder Autosuggest is not an option for me. I need this ComboViewer.
If you need any further infos please let me know.

EDIT:
I now have come pretty far.

```
comboViewer.getCombo().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.keyCode == SWT.ESC) {
                    myFilter.clearSearchString();
                } else if (e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 122) {
                    myFilter.appendToSearchString(e.character);
                } else if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) {
                    myFilter.appendToSearchString(e.character);
                }
                comboViewer.refresh();
            }

        });
```

The only thing I'm missing is: I'd like to see the entered Text somewhere in the ComboViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Your ComboViewer supports filtering of data via the setFilters() or addFilter() methods. These methods expect ViewerFilter objects as arguments.

For each registered ViewerFilter object the select() method is called. The method returns true if the data should be shown and false if it should be filtered.

So add the filter once.
Then add a KeyListener to your
control updating the filter and trigger a viewer.refresh() afterwards.

```
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerFilter;

public class PersonFilter extends ViewerFilter {

  private String searchString;

  public void setSearchText(String s) {
    // ensure that the value can be used for matching 
    this.searchString = ".*" + s + ".*";
  }

  @Override
  public boolean select(Viewer viewer, 
      Object parentElement, 
      Object element) {
    if (searchString == null || searchString.length() == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    Person p = (Person) element;
    if (p.getFirstName().matches(searchString)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (p.getLastName().matches(searchString)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't add a KeyListener to the ComboViewer.<br/> See here [http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FComboViewer.html](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FComboViewer.html)

Comment: You could do `getCombo().addKeyListener(...)`

Comment: I updated my question, cause i like to see what I have typed so far.

Comment: You need to add SWT.DROP_DOWN when creating the ComboViewer: `new ComboViewer(parent, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.READ_ONLY)`

Comment: When i use `SWT.DROP_DOWN` then the ComboBox expands when i enter text. but the entered Text will not be displayed. I think this is due to `comboViewer.refresh()`

Comment: It is definitely because of `comboViewer.refresh()`. Eventually it calls `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboViewer.listRemoveAll()` which in turn calls `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.removeAll()` which calls `clearText()`.

Comment: have you been able to find a solution?